# Using the Firestore REST API to Update a Document Field

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I've been searching for a pretty long time but I can't figure out how to update a field in a document using the Firestore REST API. I've looked on other questions but they haven't helped me since I'm getting a different error:

> {'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Request contains an invalid argument.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'oil', 'description': "Error expanding 'fields' parameter. Cannot find matching fields for path 'oil'."}]}]}}

I'm getting this error even though I know that the "oil" field exists in the document. I'm writing this in Python.

My request body (field is the field in a document and value is the value to set that field to, both strings received from user input):

```
{
    "fields": {
        field: {
            "integerValue": value
        }
    }
}
```

My request (authorizationToken is from a different request, dir is also a string from user input which controls the directory):

```
requests.patch("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/aethia-resource-management/databases/(default)/documents/" + dir + "?updateMask.fieldPaths=" + field, data = body, headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + authorizationToken}).json()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the the official docs ([1](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/patch),[2](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/DocumentMask), and [3](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents#Document.FIELDS.fields)), [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/http.proto) and a [nice article](https://engineering.flosports.tv/google-cloud-firestore-document-crud-with-php-1df1c084e45b), for the example you have provided you should use the following:

requests.patch("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects{projectId}/databases/{databaseId}/documents/{document_path}?updateMask.fieldPaths=field")

Your request body should be:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "field": {
            "integerValue": Value
        }
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind that if you want to update multiple fields and values you should specify each one separately.
Example:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{projectId}/databases/{databaseId}/documents/{document_path}?updateMask.fieldPaths=[Field1]&updateMask.fieldPaths=[Field2]
```

and the request body would have been:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "field": {
      "integerValue": Value
    },
    "Field2": {
      "stringValue": "Value2"
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a way I have tested which allows you to update some fields of a document without affecting the rest.

This sample code creates a document under collection users with 4 fields, then tries to update 3 out of 4 fields (which leaves the one not mentioned unaffected)

```
from google.cloud import firestore

db = firestore.Client()

#Creating a sample new Document “aturing” under collection “users”
doc_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(u'aturing')
doc_ref.set({
    u'first': u'Alan',
    u'middle': u'Mathison',
    u'last': u'Turing',
    u'born': 1912
})


#updating 3 out of 4 fields (so the last should remain unaffected)

doc_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(u'aturing')
doc_ref.update({
    u'first': u'Alan',
    u'middle': u'Mathison',
    u'born': 2000
})

#printing the content of all docs under users
users_ref = db.collection(u'users')
docs = users_ref.stream()

for doc in docs:
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

**EDIT: 10/12/2019**

**PATCH with REST API**

I have reproduced your issue and it seems like you are not converting your request body to a json format properly.

You need to use `json.dumps()` to convert your request body to a valid json format.

A working example is the following:

```
import requests
import json

endpoint = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/databases/(default)/documents/[COLLECTION]/[DOCUMENT_ID]?currentDocument.exists=true&updateMask.fieldPaths=[FIELD_1]"

body = {
    "fields" : {
        "[FIELD_1]" : {
            "stringValue" : "random new value"
        }
    }
}

data = json.dumps(body)

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer [AUTH_TOKEN]"}
print(requests.patch(endpoint, data=data,  headers=headers).json())
```

Comment: This isn't the issue I have, which is that for some reason it's telling me that a **field doesn't exist even though I know it does.**

Comment: I have edited my answer providing a new way I have tested. (note that i used python as you have used it in the tags)

Comment: I need to use the REST API. I can't use the client. This is because I need to be able to access my database from a platform that doesn't allow me to install external packages but allows me to send HTTP requests.

Comment: Could you please provide us with the data model you have ? and what fields you are trying to update ? In addition to any other useful info. Also check this[1] and make sure you are not missing anything from the process. Make sure you are not forgetting to specify the collection/ collection groups as well. [1]: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/

Comment: You have all the information that you need in my post. You shouldn't need anything else, nor do I have anything else to give. Regardless, I will explain it again: I don't know if this is an issue with Firestore or me, but when I try to input the name of my document field ("oil"), even though I am 100% certain that it exists, it gives me the error shown in my post. I am sending a PATCH request using the REST API to update a document using the endpoint for updating document fields. I **cannot** use the client SDK as the platform I am using this for only supports HTTP requests.

Comment: Based on your question, I thought it was working for one field but not for another.

Comment: I have updated the answer and now it should be solving your issue. @SkillsPlays

Answer (score 0):

I found the official documentation to not to be of much use since there was no example mentioned. This is the API end-point for your firestore database

PATCH [https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}/databases/(default)/documents/{COLLECTION_NAME}/{DOCUMENT_NAME}](https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/%7BYOUR_PROJECT_ID%7D/databases/(default)/documents/%7BCOLLECTION_NAME%7D/%7BDOCUMENT_NAME%7D)

the following code is the body of your API request

```
 {
  "fields": {
    "first_name": {
      "stringValue":"Kurt"
    },
    "name": {
      "stringValue":"Cobain"
    },
    "band": {
      "stringValue":"Nirvana"
    }
  }
}
```

The response you should get upon successful update of the database should look like

```
{
    "name": "projects/{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}/databases/(default)/documents/{COLLECTION_ID/{DOC_ID}",
    {
  "fields": {
    "first_name": {
      "stringValue":"Kurt"
    },
    "name": {
      "stringValue":"Cobain"
    },
    "band": {
      "stringValue":"Nirvana"
    }
  }
   "createTime": "{CREATE_TIME}",
    "updateTime": "{UPDATE_TIME}"
```

Note that performing the above action would result in a new document being created, meaning that any fields that existed previously but have NOT been mentioned in the "fields" body will be deleted. In order to preserve fields, you'll have to add

```
?updateMask.fieldPaths={FIELD_NAME}  --> to the end of your API call (for each individual field that you want to preserve).

For example:

PATCH https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}/databases/(default)/documents/{COLLECTION_NAME}/{DOCUMENT_NAME}?updateMask.fieldPaths=name&updateMask.fieldPaths=band&updateMask.fieldPaths=age. --> and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

the rest api documentation is wrong. you can not have the document name in the url path, you have to put ?documentId={doc.name/id} but if you put the ?updateMask.fieldPaths={field.name} it creates a new document with that in the name. such as {docId}?updateMask.fieldPaths={field.name} it works if the document does not already exist, but if it does it returns error 409 'document already exists'. using 'PATCH' method, and not sure what to do. oh and if you put a & instead of the ? for the updateMask, it complains about cant find 'updateMask' parameter. using c#/Unity and the rest api btw because the sdk does not support using with desktop builds as of yet. only in beta so it works only while working in the editor.

Comment: this is my url im using

Uri = $"{baseURL}projects/{projectId}/databases/(default)/documents/{path}/{docId}?currentDocument.exists=true&updateMask.fieldPaths=d" and this is the error i get back when i run it

Status: 400
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"updateMask.fieldPaths\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'updateMask' could not be found in request message.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"currentDocument.exists\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'currentDocument' could not be found in request message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"